# Can this proof of the Chain Rule be salvaged?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof, chain-rule

**Chain Rule:** Let $U$, $V$, and $W$ be normed spaces, with $U'\subseteq U$ and $V'\subseteq V$ open. If $f:U'\rightarrow V$ is differentiable at $a\in U$ and $g:V\rightarrow W$ is differentiable at $b=f(a)$, then the function $g \circ f:U'\rightarrow W$ is differentiable at $a$, and
$$(g\circ f)' (a) = g'(f(a))\circ f'(a).$$

The following proof -which suffers from an unjustified step- is very similar to the one found in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, but it seems to me slightly more intuitive: we wish to find the best linear approximation $L:U\rightarrow W$ at $a$. Considering that $f'(a)$ is the best linear approximation $U\rightarrow V$ at $a$, and $g'(b)$ is the best linear approximation $V\rightarrow W$ at $b=f(a)$, a plausible candidate for $L$ is $g'(b)\circ f'(a)$.

---

*Proof:*
Letting $f'(a)=L_f$ and $g'(b)=L_g$ we may write
$$f(a+h)=f(a)+L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h) \ \text{, and}$$
$$g(b+k)=g(b)+L_g(k)+\varepsilon_g(k)$$
where $|\varepsilon_f(h)|/|h| \rightarrow 0$ as $|h|\rightarrow 0$ and $|\varepsilon_g(k)|/|k| \rightarrow 0$ as $|k|\rightarrow 0$. Wishing to approximate $g\circ f$ around $a$ with a linear function, we may continue as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g(f(a+h)) & = g[f(a)+L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)] \\
 & = g(b)+L_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]+\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)] \\
 & = g(b)+L_g[L_f(h)]+L_g[\varepsilon_f(h)]+\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and it remains to be shown that
$$\frac{|L_g[\varepsilon_f(h)]+\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]|}{|h|}\rightarrow 0\ \text{as} \ |h|\rightarrow 0.$$
Employing the triangle inequality we have that the LHS above is lesser or equal than
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 &  \frac{|L_g[\varepsilon_f(h)]|}{|h|}+\frac{|\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]|}{|h|} \\
 & = \left|L_g\left[\frac{\varepsilon_f(h)}{|h|}\right]\right| 
    + \left(\frac{\left|\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]\right|}{\left|L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)\right|}\right)\left(\frac{\left|L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)\right|}{\left|h\right|}\right)\\
& \le \left|L_g\left[\frac{\varepsilon_f(h)}{|h|}\right]\right| 
    + \left(\frac{\left|\varepsilon_g[L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)]\right|}{\left|L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)\right|}\right)\left(\frac{|L_f(h)|}{|h|}+\frac{|\varepsilon_f(h)|}{|h|}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
As $h\rightarrow 0$ the first term tends to zero by the fact that $L_g$ is continuous and that $|\varepsilon(h)|/|h|\rightarrow 0$; the second term tends to zero by definition of $\varepsilon_g$, and the last term tends to zero by $L_f$ being bounded and by the definition of $\varepsilon_f$.

---

The problem comes at the end of the proof, when dividing by $|L_f(h)+\varepsilon_f(h)|$, since I see no reason to believe the quantity must be non-zero around $a$ i.e. one may not be justified in dividing by it. **Can the proof be salvaged somehow?**

Comment: Why are you using $\circ$ for multiplication?

Comment: The thing you're concerned about happens only if $L_f\rightarrow 0$, right? But if that's the case, I think you can handle that separately earlier in the proof, and then assume that it is not.

Comment: I’m too tired to look at this in detail, but trust me, you do not want to salvage this proof. Divison is, and will always be a nightmare, so it’s best to avoid it whenever possible (you only find this intuitive, because that’s how people try to do things in 1D). I’d suggest you take a look at Loomis and Sternberg’s *Advanced Calculus*, section 3.5, where they prove the basic lemmas regarding the various classes of functions ($\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{o}$, big and little-oh), and how they behave under sums and compositions. This makes the chain rule next-to-trivial (see section 3.6’s ending).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can savage your proof. Note that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow0}\frac{|\varepsilon_{g}(k)|}{|k|}=0
$$
implies that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\sup_{k^{\prime}\in\overline{B(0,1)}}\frac{|\varepsilon
_{g}(tk^{\prime})|}{t}=0
$$
(it is actually equivalent, but we don't need that). To see this, observe that
if $\lim_{k\rightarrow0}\frac{|\varepsilon_{g}(k)|}{|k|}=0$, then for every
$\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\varepsilon_{g}
(k)|\leq\epsilon|k|$ for all $k$ with $0<|k|\leq\delta$. Since $\varepsilon
_{g}(0)=0$, this inequality holds also for $k=0$. In particular if $k^{\prime
}\in\overline{B(0,1)}$ and $0\leq t\leq\delta$, we have that $|tk^{\prime
}|\leq\delta$ and so $|\varepsilon_{g}(tk^{\prime})|\leq\epsilon t$, or,
equivalently, $\sup_{k^{\prime}\in\overline{B(0,1)}}|\varepsilon
_{g}(tk^{\prime})|\leq\epsilon t$. This shows that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}
\sup_{k^{\prime}\in\overline{B(0,1)}}\frac{|\varepsilon_{g}(tk^{\prime})|}
{t}=0$.

Since $|L_{f}(h)+\varepsilon_{f}(h)|\leq C|h|$, given $\epsilon>0$ take
$\delta>0$ such that $\sup_{k^{\prime}\in\overline{B(0,1)}}|\varepsilon
_{g}(tk^{\prime})|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{C}t/C$ for all $0\leq t\leq\delta$.
Then
$$
|\varepsilon_{g}(L_{f}(h)+\varepsilon_{f}(h))|=\left\vert \varepsilon
_{g}\left(  \frac{L_{f}(h)+\varepsilon_{f}(h)}{C|h|}C|h|\right)  \right\vert
\leq\sup_{k^{\prime}\in\overline{B(0,1)}}|\varepsilon_{g}(C|h|k^{\prime}
)|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{C}C|h|
$$
for all $0<|h|\leq\delta/C$. This proves that
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{|\varepsilon_{g}(L_{f}(h)+\varepsilon_{f}(h))|}
{|h|}=0.
$$