# Error in Spivak's Chain Rule proof?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-explanation, chain-rule

Recently I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629258/can-this-proof-of-the-chain-rule-be-salvaged), regarding how to deal with a quotient on a proof of the chain rule. I've come to wonder if a step in Spipvak's proof in *Calculus on Manifolds* needs a similar justification. The question is at the very end of the post.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Considering that **Problem 1-10** requires us to prove that any linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is bounded/continuous, my guess is that the intented justification of $(6)$ tending to zero is:

$$\frac{\mu(\phi(x))}{x-a} = \frac{\mu(\phi(x))}{\phi(x)}\frac{\phi(x)}{x-a}$$

where

$$\frac{|\mu(\phi(x))|}{|\phi(x)|}\le M \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{|\phi(x)|}{|x-a|} = 0$$

for some $M\in \mathbb{R}$. So that ${\mu(\phi(x))}/(x-a)\to 0$ whenever $x\to a$. However

$$\textbf{what justifies dividing by } \phi(x)?$$

Comment: The more useful way to view boundedness of a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is as the existence of a constant $M > 0$ such that $\lVert T(x) \rVert \leq M \lVert x \rVert$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that this doesn't involve division by anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, why bother dividing? We have for any $x\neq a$,
\begin{align}
\frac{\|\mu(\phi(x))\|}{\|x-a\|}&\leq \frac{\|\mu\|\cdot \|\phi(x)\|}{\|x-a\|}=\|\mu\|\cdot \frac{\|\phi(x)\|}{\|x-a\|}.
\end{align}
The RHS vanishes as $x\to a$ because of $(4)$. So, squeeze theorem tells you the LHS also vanishes as $x\to a$. This proves $(7)$.

Here, I wrote $\|\mu\|$ to mean the operator norm of the linear map $\mu$. But really all we care about is there exists a number $M\geq 0$ such that for all $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^m$, $\|\mu(\xi)\|\leq M\|\xi\|$.

Comment: Furthermore, Q1-10 itself is phrased multiplicatively, so why even bother with division?